# Java - loading resources directory

Tags: java

This is from Chapter 4 of the book "Core Java 9 for the impatient".

> Resources can have subdirectories which can be relative or absolute.
>   For example, MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/menus.txt")
>   locates config/menus.txt in the directory that contains the root of
>   the package to which MyClass belongs.

This is the confusing line - "the directory that contains the root of the package to which MyClass belongs." Can someone tell me which directory this line refers to ? An example would be nice.

Comment: The leading slash means that it ceases to be relative to the location of the current class's package, just as in a file system it means that it ceases to be relative to the current working directory. The slash refers to the directory that contains the *head* of the package hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Packages and folders**

In normal Java, there is a one-to-one mapping of an apps packages and the file-system contained in a given jar file, of which root ('/') maps to the [default (unnamed or root) package](https://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-is-the-default-package/126). The `MyClass.class.getReourceAsStream()` method loads resources from a path relative to the package `MyClass` is in, rooted at the location pointed to by the environment variable `CLASSPATH` (which usually points to where your jars are kept). So, if `MyClass` is actually `com.mycompany.myapp.MyClass`, then resources relative to this class are in the `/com/mycompany/myapp/` directory.

**Sources**

In a [standard java/maven project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), maven would compile your java code from `/src/main/java` into a target directory and copy anything under `src/main/resources` into the same target directory structure. To locate resource source files in your application relative to the class `com.mycompany.myapp.MyClass`, you would look in the `src/main/resources/com/mycompany/myapp/` folder. However, with your specific example, as @user207421 points out in the comment below, your path starts with a slash (`/`). This makes the path to the resource 'absolute', not 'relative' to your class. Your path starts at the root and thus the file needs to be in the directory `/config` in the jar. In a [standard java/maven project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), this file would be held in the directory `/src/main/resources/config/`.

**Generated sources**

It should be mentioned that even in a [standard java/maven project](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) it is possible for resource files to be sourced from directories other than `src/main/resources`. For example, it is common practice to generate code *and* resources into the `target/generated-sources` directory, and have those files compiled and copied into the resultant jar, and I've worked in some shops that care enough to generate sources and resources into separate directories under `target`, so they have `target/generated-resources` too, though for most projects this is considered overkill for generated sources. At assembly time, both the `src/main/resources` and the `target/generated-resources` directories should be copied into the root of the jar file.

**Normal Java**

Also, to emphasise the point I made at the start, this is only true for normal Java; that is, Java that follows the textbook approach to having `.java` text files from a filesystem define classes and having those classes 'compiled' into a jar file that is loaded by the runtime interpreter. Technically none of this is necessary and some implementations of java look nothing like this. IBM has in the past written a version of java where classes are loaded from databases rather than jar files, and if you add in runtime weaving and class generation then things can very quickly get really far from the 'normal' model described above.

Comment: No. It refers to `/config/menus.txt` under wherever the CLASSPATH refers to. The `src` directory isn't there at runtime, and the leading slash removes the dependency on the current class.

Comment: Thanks. I had completely missed the `/` at the start of the config path. I have updated the answer to mention relative and absolute paths and to discuss how the src maps to the runtime.